# Powerbuilder randomly crashes during runtime using powerbuilder ver 10.5

Tags: runtime, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

we currently have an application that runs perfectly well until 1 day the users started getting error message stating that .exe has stopped working. when we tried replicating the error, we observed that it is in random. you can do saving again and again but after a few tries you will get the same error again.

i tried optimizing, regenerating even tried rebuilding the whole application but the problem still persists.

can somebody point me whats causing this insane issue. its getting me crazy..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any more information that could be useful? please also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you hope to get some good answers

Comment: “Randomly crashes” or “stops responding“? Your wording is suggesting both. Have you gone through http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Abnormal_Termination/abnormal_termination.html ?

Comment: Something change on the workstations (like an update perhaps)?  User permissions change?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for responding. We used PBDEBUG and no significant errors registered. We also did optimize, regen, rebuild the pbls still we receive the same error. We even tried setting up a new database to another machine and connect the pb exe on that new database but still we experience the same error. The error didnt appear much often, when we tried installing the pb exe in win7 os.

Comment: We are currently using win10 on client pcs,  win server 2003 sp2 and sql server 2000 environment on our servers and just recently, the working pb exe is experiencing abnormal termination. Our system is not on auto update so not sure if there is an update. 

If it is an update, can you tell me which one to look at?
Thanks again for your replies

Comment: I have had similar problems and came to the conclusion they were related to the middleware: some versions of ODBC drivers (to MySQL) did cause the problem.  By getting the latest version, it was OK.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is difficult to guide you. But such errors usually occur because the process uses too much memory and windows kills it. Try to check the code so that CREATE statements are not executed within a loop. Execute the DESTROY statements when you no longer use an object. If you still can't solve it, you can run the garbage collector with:

```
GarbageCollect()
```